# Конвертация массива имён объектов в список объектов

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется список объектов `(Photo, Video, Gallery, PhotoMode, VideoMode)`.
На вход поступает массив строк `(string[] modes)` – имён режимов фото, как его конвертировать в список фоторежимов (желательно используя LINQ)?
Сам список:

```
static public List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
```

Comment: Можешь использовать рефлексию для получения объектов.

Comment: Можете код показать того, что у вас есть? Я не совсем задачу пойму просто.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<object>();
//modeNames - it`s array of string
modeNames.ToList().ForEach(mode => {
    //use reflection to find a type and create a instance of object
    var t = Type.GetType($"MyNamespaceName.{mode}");
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    list.Add(obj);
});
```

Должно сработать.
В переменной list будут упакованы экземпляры классов фото-режимов. 
Я бы не рекомендовал использовать упаковку ибо можно огрести кучу ошибок. Можно привести все режимы к определенному интерфейсу, реализовать во всех классах этот интерфейс и сохранять в `List<IPhotoMode>`.